# Android Studio importing library Gradle: error: package org.simpleframework.xml does not exist

Tags: gradle, android-studio, simple-framework

I can't make project in Android Studio.
When compile project I have some errors:

```
Gradle: error: package org.simpleframework.xml does not exist
Gradle: error: cannot find symbol class Element
Gradle: error: cannot find symbol class Element
```

I add jar manually and from Dependencies to project.

How to fix it ?!

OK, I fix It.
The problem was solved. I add manually to config file library libs/simple-xml-2.7.jar.

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar', 'libs/commons-net-3.3.jar', 'libs/simple-xml-2.7.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use Maven to declare that dependency in your **build.gradle**, like this:

```
dependencies {
    [...]
    compile 'org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7'
}
```

also make sure that you have maven central declared as a repository:

```
repositories {
    [...]
    mavenCentral()
}
```

---

Another common solution if you want to download the .jars by yourself is to include any .jar inside libs/, like that:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    [...]
}
```

Anyway, make sure that you don't include a library more than once, that could cause problems.